# Can I join two tables on an Integer type column and the second with CSV

Tags: sql, csv, split

I have two tables and the columns on which have to join are as

Table 1:
Column on which I have to join

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and
Table 2

```
Column 2
1,2,3
1,3,4
1,5
2,3,4
```

How can I join both tables on these columns.

P.S. string_split is of no use here.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can* do that.  In standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select . . . 
from t1 join
     t2
     on ',' || t2.ids || ',' like '%,' || t1.id || ','%' ;
```

The exact syntax might depend on the database you are using.

But you don't want to.  You want to fix your data model.  SQL has a great way to store lists of ids that match something.  It is called a table with one row per id pair that matches.  Strings are the wrong way to store lists, and strings are the wrong way to store integers.

Comment: Thanks this is useful. But it won't take all the values in column 2 and this will create one row for only one reason.

Comment: @NitinPathak . . . Huh?  This does exactly what the question asks.  It joins the value in the first table to all elements in the second table.